# What does "pfft" mean in American English?

Tags: american-english, interjections

Person 1: You're an idiot.

Person 2: Pfft

Comment: The same usage in BrE.

Comment: Please tell us where you are quoting this dialogue from.  If you made it up yourself, how do you know the word "pftt"?

Comment: @user105719  Please put your answer in an answer and not in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I would have said that it isn't a word, but a *non-lexical sound* - a vocal sound that people make and the meaning is recognisable.

Having said that, I was surprised to find [it is in the dictionary](https://www.lexico.com/definition/pfft)!

> "used to express a contemptuous or dismissive attitude".

Other examples:

- Hmmm
- Ha!
- Mmmmm
- Aah
- Uh-huh
- Aaaw

Comment: ...and perhaps *Tsch*!

Comment: @WeatherVane As in "Tsch! I forgot one!" Yeah, I could have gone on all day, I think it makes the point ;)

Comment: It's worth noting that the other non-lexical sounds you posted mean different things. It's also probably arguable whether or not some of them are words in their own right.

Comment: What British people call 'tutting' used to be rendered in _The Dandy_ (a kid's comic) in speech balloons as 'Tsk Tsk', and, as a kid, I really thought that some people _said_ that.

Comment: In French, when people go 'pfffffft', it means 'you are an idiot'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey They also said "coo!" in comics and I've no idea who makes that noise.